# Predicting host-pathogen gene interaction networks

Tags: genomics, genomes, gene-regulation, network, host-pathogen-interaction

**Background**

What we have are:

- ~20 genome sequences for a host species that come with gene annotations
- Several sequenced genomes for parasite/pathogens of these hosts

**Question**

What are the possible ways of predicting gene-to-gene interactions or gene regulatory networks between hosts and parasites?

Comment: About what kind of interactions do you think? Transcription factors from parasites that influence the host?

Comment: thanks for the question. at the simplest level an interaction would involve binding, e.g. gene A that expresses a transcription factor that represses gene B via binding it's promoter sequence would be considered an interaction between gene A and gene B.

Comment: there is no way by which you can predict genetic interactions based on sequence alone.. You need more information such as protein-DNA interactions, expression correlation, protein-protein interaction etc

Comment: exactly! which is why i am asking the question i suppose, you hinted at some ideas there thank you - could you expand on them?